# popstate returns event.state is undefined

Tags: jquery, html, history, pushstate

I am learning about history in HTML5, in this example (open the JavaScript browser console to see error) the `event.state.url` returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

Look and help: http://jsfiddle.net/un4Xk/

Comment: url doesnot exists any more

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`event` is the jQuery event object, not the DOM one.

To access the DOM event object, use `event.originalEvent`: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/un4Xk/1/.

```
var state = event.originalEvent.state;
```

Remember that the state is only defined when the new state has data, so it is not available when clicking and then going back to the initial state:

1. initial state
2. link to state 1
3. back button to initial state (no data available)

It is, however, available when clicking, clicking another time and then going back:

1. initial state
2. link to state 1
3. link to state 2
4. back button to state 1 (data available)

Comment: @Caio Tarifa: Well, the initial state is the one when the page loads, so you know that it should revert things back to the original state. E.g. in this case `#return` should be emptied back: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/un4Xk/2/.

Comment: Could you explain what this line does? `var initialPop = !popped && location.href == initialURL;`

Comment: @drozzy: I don't know for sure. It was part of @Caio Tarifa's original code as he posted in the question. It looks like it's to prevent the code from executing when the page is initially loaded, as `popstate` is executed as well in that case: http://jsfiddle.net/un4Xk/3/.

Comment: Unfortunately, all Fiddles have lost their strings :(

Comment: change your jsfiddle link