# Get state of pushstate() from popState()

Tags: javascript, history.js

I have this:

```
history.pushState({id:1}, 'new title', new_url);
```

Now, when someone uses the browser's back button, how do I retrieve the id (1)?

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
   event.state.id # gives an error
});
```

I tried the above (as suggested in an answer) and the error I get is "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), you could also use:

`var currentState = history.state;`

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I managed finally to find the answer here:

[popstate returns event.state is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860960/popstate-returns-event-state-is-undefined)

It says:

Event is the jQuery event object, not the DOM one.

To access the DOM event object, use event.originalEvent: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/un4Xk/1/.

var state = event.originalEvent.state;
Remember that the state is only defined when the new state has data, so it is not available when clicking and then going back to the initial state:

```
initial state
link to state 1
back button to initial state (no data available)
```

It is, however, available when clicking, clicking another time and then going back:

```
initial state
link to state 1
link to state 2
back button to state 1 (data available)
```

Comment: I missed the data part. Thanks