# jQuery bind popstate event not passed

Tags: jquery, html, html5-history

I'm coding a little demo for the History API. And I'm struggling with this:

```
$(window).bind('popstate',  
    function(event) {
        console.log('pop: ' + event.state);
    });
```

It logs 'pop: undefined' when I click on the 'Previous' button...

But if I do this instead, things are working like expected :

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    console.log('pop: ' + event.state);
};
```

It logs 'pop: [object Object]' this time...

So it's like jQuery doesn't pass the event object to the callback.
Is there a problem with jQuery ? Or did I mess something ?

Comment: Which browser? Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688164/window-bind-popstate yet?

Comment: thx for your comment, it helped to me to understand better what's the problem, so I changed a little bit my question. It is not the same than the one that you point, because it's not a problem on the first load.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In the first instance, you're getting a normalized jQuery event object. In the second instance, you're getting the browser's event object. I assume that jQuery hasn't completed normalizing all the new HTML5 events and related attributes. Until then, you'll need to access the original event object. You can do that through the jQuery event object via the originalEvent property. You can find some additional details and examples here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/7860960/popstate-returns-event-state-is-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860960/popstate-returns-event-state-is-undefined)

```
event.originalEvent.state
```

Comment: Nice catch! I didn't see this question when I searched before asking :(

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to take full credit for the catch but stackoverflow did it for me. I happened to notice it in the Related list in the right margin. All the best in your development efforts!