# Retrieving browser state information with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, state

I am using states to remember which links the user has clicked, in order. Currently, I just want to alert the state information, but this code somehow doesn't work:

```
function onLinhaClick(obj) {
    $("#linha").children("a").off("click");
    history.pushState({ item : $(obj).attr("data-value") }, $(obj).children("span").html(), $(obj).attr("href"));
    $(obj).nextAll().remove();
    $("#linha").children("a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        onLinhaClick($(this));
    });
}

function onMateriaClick(obj) {
    $("#materias").children("a").off("click");
    history.pushState({ value : $(obj).attr("data-value") }, $(obj).children("span").html(), $(obj).attr("href"));
            /*some not important code*/
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#linha").children("a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        onLinhaClick($(this));
    });
    $("#materias").children("a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        onMateriaClick($(this));
    });
});

$(window).on("popstate", function(e) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(e.state));
});
```

The alert just prints "undefined", and I followed several documentation which didn't help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$(window).on("popstate", function(e) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(e.state));
});
```

to

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(e.state));
}
```

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299980/jquery-bind-popstate-event-not-passed)

Comment: It works as expected now, although it is still a little shady for me why jquery doesn't work...