# Back button works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, back-button, pushstate

I'm working on my page and can't find answer for my issue.

I'm using window.history.pushstate, and onpopstate event, here is my code:

```
changeContent = function(href) {
  window.history.pushState({}, '', href);
  if (href == "/") {
    $('#main').load('main.html');
  } else {
    $('#main').html('<iframe id="gallery" src="photos'+href+'/index.html"></iframe>');
  }
};

$(window).on("popstate", function(e) {
  changeContent(location.pathname);
});

$(document).on("click", ".galleryLink", function() {
  var href = $( this ).attr( "href" );
  changeContent(href)
  return false;
});
```

i.e.

google page -> my main page -> gallery -> back button -> my main page -> back button -> my main page -> back button -> my main page

What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Got it!**

Line:

```
window.history.pushState({}, '', href);
```

should be inside

```
$(document).on("click", ".galleryLink", function()
```

I put it inside

```
changeContent = function(href)
```

this was my fault... :-)

Comment: I'm not using JQuery and have the same problem. I can't put a funciton as third parameter, how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here it says, jQuery has problems with capturing that `popstate` event and you should take the native `onpopstate`.

[jQuery bind popstate event not passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299980/jquery-bind-popstate-event-not-passed).

However I wonder why it works once?

Comment: My jQuery capturing works great, I found an answer, but can't answer my own question now (reputation to low)

Comment: @YaPKnn Ah yeah, finally got it too, changecontent gets called on popstate too yeah.